# How can I make Google now-ish Animations in android xml

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

How can I make Google now-ish Animations in android xml I know that this question is noobish but I'm still a beginner

Comment: What do you mean by Google now animation, can you be more specific with screenshot ? That'll help understand what animation you are interested in.

Comment: Do you want activity transitions and stuff like cards coming up, Google Now activity opening when you open it?

Comment: The way that cards appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find many great animations on GitHub searching for it. I found one that might be intersting, check this one out:

https://github.com/uchidaknet/AndroidCardUIWithAnimationSample